# Visual Studio / Qt: Including a library (Qt) with its subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, include

I'm trying to get Mumble running by its original C++/Qt-Code in Visual Studio Ultimate.
I downloaded and installed Qt, and I added

```
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include
```

and

```
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\bin
```

to the "Additional include directories" (Project config -> config -> C/C++ -> General). This fixes most of the include issues.
However, the source code includes some subdirectory-based includes, like

```
#include <QtCore>
```

which is located at

```
C:\Qt\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore
```

If I add that very directory to the additional include directories, Visual Studio will accept the include command. Otherwise, it says sth. like "Source cannot be opened".

How can I add the WHOLE Qt include folder, including its subdirectories, to the Visual Studio library? I doubt I am expected to add 42 subfolders manually, each of them containing at least one more subfolder.
Or am I doing something wrong? I ain't even talking of the VS QT Addin, because I didn't get that running at all.
How come I am the only one around with these problems?
Appreciate your help very much

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you not to use global qt includes like QtCore, because it will make compilation very slow. Except using it with precompiled headers.

I use following file as a part of my precompiled headers. If you use this file you will not need any Qt includes in code at all.

```
#pragma once

// qt_includes.h

#ifdef QT_CORE_LIB
# include <QtCore>
#endif

#ifdef QT_GUI_LIB
# include <QtGui>
#endif

#ifdef QT_WIDGETS_LIB
# include <QtWidgets>
#endif

#ifdef QT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB
# include <QtMultimedia>
#endif

#ifdef QT_NETWORK_LIB
# include <QtNetwork>
#endif

#ifdef QT_XML_LIB
# include <QtXml>
#endif

#ifdef QT_QML_LIB
# include <QtQml>
#endif

#ifdef QT_QUICK_LIB
# include <QtQuick>
#endif

#ifdef QT_SQL_LIB
# include <QtSql>
#endif
```